# ValueError: Found infinity in column x

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got an error ValueError: Found infinity in column x.
Traceback says

```
---> 20     model.fit(df)

    242             df[‘x’] = pd.to_numeric(df[‘x’])
    243             if np.isinf(df[‘x’].values).any():
--> 244                 raise ValueError('Found infinity in column y.')
    245         df[‘d’] = pd.to_datetime(df[‘d’])
    246         if df[‘d’].isnull().any():
```

I really cannot understand what is the meaning of this error message because I do not have infinity number in df.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

My codes is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet

for  i in range(10):
    df = pd.read_csv('data'+ i + '.csv', encoding='shift-jis')

    model = Prophet()
    model.fit(df)

    future_data = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=12, freq = 'm')
    forecast_data = model.predict(future_data)

    model.plot(forecast_data)
    model.plot_components(forecast_data)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Pls share a part of your dataset and code

Comment: How you check it? `print (df[np.isinf(df['x'])])` ?

Comment: @jezrael  `print (df[np.isinf(df['x'])])` shows `Empty DataFrame
Columns: [x, test1, test2, test3, d]
Index: []`

Comment: @Alex i add my codes,if you know something,please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to remove `infinity` values from your DataFrame. It can be done like this:

```
DataFrame.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

When you replaced `infinity` values to `NaN` you can remove it from DataFrame via `dropna`:

```
DataFrame.dropna(subset=["YourColumn"], how="all")
```

Comment: thank you.I added your codes `df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)` upper `model.fit(df)`,but same error happens.I rewrote `df['x']=df['x'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)` so ValueError: Dataframe has less than 2 non-NaN rows. happens.What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Comment: @user10102827 after replacing infinity values to NaN you need to remove rows with NaN values via `DataFrame.dropna(subset=["YourColumn1", "YourColumn2"], how="all")`